# What's the right ZMQ architecture for my scenario?

Tags: architecture, message-queue, zeromq, publish-subscribe, messaging

I have a service A that every once in a while needs to send a message to a cluster of services B1, B2 ... BN. Then all of these services need to receive that message reliably, and send a confirmation back to A. After A receives the confirmation from all services from cluster B, it needs to send a message to another cluster of services C1, C2 ... CN.

What is the right ZMQ pattern for this, and what sockets should I pick? It seems like a router - dealer situation where A is a Router and Bs and Cs are Dealers. I need the transmission of these messages to have delivery guarantee so not sure if I can do pub sub here.